# Load component view from lazy route child component based on condition

Tags: angular

Loading component view from another component which is coming from lazy route child component, working on page refresh and it loads perfectly but if I change view inside and then route child does not work

I have PageModule like this

```
imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', component: Page },
        ]),
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        Page,
        PageV1,
        PageV2,
    ],
```

Page.component.ts

Here I should load component PageV1 or PageV2 based on condition

```
If (condition) {
// load PageV1
} else {
// load PageV2
}
```

Page.component.html

```
<pageV1 *ngIf=“someCondition; else secondPage></pageV1>
<ng-template #secondPage>
    <pageV2></pageV2>
</ng-template>
```

If I directly pass PageV2 component to route child it work’s fine but conditionally loading doesn’t work, did I make any mistake on page loading

Comment: You have just missed double quote in ngif condition and just check by !ngif condition rather than else condition. just like
 <pageV1 *ngIf=“someCondition"></pageV1>
    <pageV2 *ngIf="!someCondition"></pageV2>

Comment: that's actually typo but that is not an issue, even I can't reach to template

Comment: have you tried with !ngIf rather than else condition?

Comment: i just tried what you suggest but no luck